# Enabling Roslyn diagnostics when running Roslyn analysis programmatically

Tags: unit-testing, mstest, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I've created a Roslyn analyzer using the VS 2015 templates. I've got everything working, including the unit tests, given the diagnostics are enabled by default.

If I set the `isEnabledByDefault` parameter on the `DiagnosticDescriptor` to `false` I can get everything working in Visual Studio by enabling the diagnostics using a `.ruleset` file. However once the diagnostics are disabled by default the unit tests won't report their results anymore.

How can I enable these disabled-by-default diagnostics during unit tests? I'm prepared to alter the way the unit tests invoke the Roslyn Compilation/Analyzer/Diagnostic/etc. results, but I haven't found a way to specify the settings given the lack of documentation I've managed to scrape from various sources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to override the diagnostic severity similar to the rule file,
the [`CompilationOptions.SpecificDiagnosticOptions`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Compilation/CompilationOptions.cs,701443a092cf7a50,references) allow for that (a compilation has `Options` that can override something like this).

I've successfully changed my analyzer to be disabled, and override the `DiagnosticVerifier.Helper` (in `Helpers`), in my pet project (see commit [`8dfc02c`](https://github.com/tiesmaster/AdhocAnalyzers/commit/8dfc02cfeda1b933fc3bf262b49c6b0fdcbfccba) for how I did that). Basically, it boils down to:

```cs
private static Compilation OverrideDiagnosticSeverity(
    Compilation compilation,
    string diagnosticId,
    ReportDiagnostic reportDiagnostic)
{
    var compilationOptions = compilation.Options;
    var specificDiagnosticOptions = compilationOptions.SpecificDiagnosticOptions;

    specificDiagnosticOptions = specificDiagnosticOptions.Add(diagnosticId, reportDiagnostic);
    var options = compilationOptions.WithSpecificDiagnosticOptions(specificDiagnosticOptions);

    return compilation.WithOptions(options);
}
```

You might want to add a flag to `VerifyCSharpDiagnostic` to do this on request of the unit test.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks! I was sure this would be yet another too specific question failing to yield any answers. So glad to be proven wrong. :)